# IP instead of localhost

Tags: asp.net, http, localhost

I have a sample project (using a webserver) working on `localhost:49350`

I would like to access that from another computer in the same network. However, entering the IP address instead of localhost (the one i get via cmd--> ipconfig) does not seem to work
(`192.168.0.17:49350`). I get a bad request (400).

Can anyone help? I am using asp.net web api and I am fairly new to this.

Thanks in advance!

Greets.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Why do you put a slash after the ip?

Comment: Which IPs is the webserver binding to? Did you configure the webserver to serve your project on localhost only?

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the port (49350) on your router, should be open for TCP.

Comment: He wants access from inside his network. Why should he open the port on the router then?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of router he has. Some routers even have a setting for wireless isolation which needs to be unchecked.

Comment: I have the Thomson TWG870U router/modem. I do not really want to open the port to outsider, only withing my network.